# will_paginate mass operations with specific page don't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

*Rails 4.2.5 and will_paginate 3.1.0.*

I was stuck for some time being unable to do mass operations (like `update_all`) with will_paginate, and while investigating I've found some strange behavior. Could anyone please explain the reason behind it?

Let's say I have 22 users in the database and `per_page = 10`:

`User.all.page(3)` will return correct users (user 21 and user 22),
however:

```
User.all.page(3).count # => 22
```

while

```
User.all.offset(2 * User.per_page).limit(User.per_page).count # => 2
```

---

The specific problem I was dealing with is that if I do something like this:

```
User.all.page(3).update_all(flagged: true)
```

I get the *first* page updated (users 1-10) and not the third one (users 21-22).

Is there a way to use will_paginate `page` method inside a controller to manipulate records within the specific page only?

---

Update:

The funny thing is that even with `.offset().limit()` mass update still won't work and I get the same results: the *first* page is updated instead of the last one (users 1-10, and not 21-22).

So while

```
User.all.offset(2 * User.per_page).limit(User.per_page).count # => 2
```

the `User.all.offset(2 * User.per_page).limit(User.per_page).update_all(flagged: true)` still updates the first 10 users and not the last 2.

The only way I came up with so far is to do `User.all.page(3).each { |user| user.update(flagged: true) }` which works fine but seems to be terribly ineffective.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add .per_page(10) to your active record query

Comment: Nope. :( Still the same. And even the `.offset().limit()` doesn't work as expected (see the update to the post).